# django is_ajax() returns false during ajax call with dataType="jsonp"

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jsonp

From what I've read, it seems to be the normal behavior.
However, is there any way in django to check that the request is coming originally from an ajax call or has at least datatype jsonp?

so far, I only do this verification in the django view.

```
if request.method == "GET": # I would like something similar to is_ajax() too
```

I've not found much help on this,
But I don't know if it is useful and if I should do this for security reasons maybe?

Thanks for the help

Comment: that is correct, because jsonp isn't really ajax. therefore, there is no way of detecting it by normal means. Instead, just check for the existence of a `callback` parameter.

Comment: I do check the existence of the callback parameter because I'm actually using this decorator https://coderwall.com/p/k8vb_a

Comment: And I use GET instead of POST as it seems there is no choice with jsonp. My script works well, but I was eventually wondering about security since I do not check for ajax call neither I have csrf protection in this view... since it is to log in I prefer to ask... (and I had to switch to jsonp because of the use of subdomains in my project).

Comment: If you used ssl, it would be more secure, but if you also wanted to use POST instead, you can, you just have to make sure that you are sending the correct CORS headers back from the server. (however, cors won't work in IE6/7)